# Change background color of ListView specific row without CustomAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm trying to change the background color of a specific row in a ListView to match a specific color in my `List<String> hexcodeList`, which contains colors hex codes. However, I'm not using a CustomAdapter for this, instead I'm overriding `getView` from `ArrayAdapter`. I want the 1st row to have the 1st color of my list, the 2nd to have the 2nd color and so on. I'm very new to Java, my first thought was to use a for statement, so the code below is what I tried with no success, since this changes the background color of all rows using the last color of `hexcodeList`.

```
ListView CoresListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewId);  
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, hexcodeList){
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View view = super.getView(position,convertView,parent);
        for (position = 0; position < hexcodeList.size(); position++) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(hexcodeList.get(position)));
        }
        return view;
    }
};

CoresListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: in the loop it will set color for all items so you need to use if statement. for specific position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On each view created you are looping through the list and setting all colors so the last color is being set for each view.

Remove the loop and just write this:

```
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(hexcodeList.get(position)));
```

getView(...) is called for each view so need of a loop.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need for loop because the `getView()` always called for each row item view.

**Try this:**

```
ListView CoresListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewId);  
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, hexcodeList){
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View view = super.getView(position,convertView,parent);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(hexcodeList.get(position)));

        return view;
    }
};

CoresListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```